# Getting the error, the source is not available when trying to download from the official ubuntu website

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, 17.10

I am unable to download any of the ubuntu versions from the official website using any of the methods, as specified on the website. I am getting the error that the source file could not be read. I have attached the screenshot for the problem faced while downloading. It can be great if someone could help.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It's a problem with your computer. Downloads are working fine.

Comment: Or maybe with the mirror, try another.